# Inserting/Saving Position after Jquery Draggable in SQL server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql, draggable

I been testing and trying for over a week, trying to save/insert the new position of an element in SQL server after dragging it from one place to another using JQuery draggable, its just not working! and i searched for people having similar problem and yet no solution worked for me so far; so i would appreciate some help!

I am using JQuery's draggable in ASP.NET C#

```
<script>
    $(function () {;
        $(".move").draggable();
    });</script>
```

and here's the label i am dragging; simple formula , just trying to save its new position in database after dragging it

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelPanelID" class="move" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" padding="90px" 
                    style="font-size: large"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Post your current code here, else no one can help

Comment: Where do you try to get the position of the draggable element? Your calling to draggable plugin looks too simple. Take a look to the [jQuery-UI API](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/). You can set an index in each element, then, through `stop()` event, re-set the positions and save it to database.

Comment: @kmsdev i am sorry for being newbie, but could you give me an example of using the stop function and calling a normal method to save data to sql ? thats what i am inquiring about, how to get the position after dragging the element then saving it to database!

Comment: Be new is not a problem. But there are who prefer that others do their job, you know. I will post a working example as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example code to reach your goal:

```
$(function(){
    $box = $('#box');
    Program.Reorder($box);

    $box.draggable({
        stop: function(){
            Program.Reorder($(this));
            Program.Save();
        }
    });
});

var Program = {

    $element: null,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,

    Reorder: function($element){
        this.$element = $element;
        this.top = this.$element.css('top').replace(/px/,'');
        this.left = this.$element.css('left').replace(/px/,'');
    },

    Save: function(){
        alert('top: ' + this.top + '\n' + 'left: ' + this.left);
        // do ajax things here
    }

};
```

As you can see this object oriented code is really simple, so I think that you will understand it easily.

Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/r35zK/)